# iOS: Post on wall of Selected FB Friends

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbdialogs

***Scenario:*** I would want to share the post to the wall of only selected friends.

***Prerequisites followed:*** 
Out of the entire list of FB Friends, select only the necessary friends and create an Array

***Steps Tried:***

***Trial 1:*** Use `FBWebDialogs` and call method `+ (void)presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:(FBSession *)session parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters handler:(FBWebDialogHandler)handler;`

In the Parameters dictionary, set value for "to".

Works perfectly fine when the recipient is only one. Cannot share if the recipient is more than one.

***Trial 2:*** Use `FBDialogs` and call `+ (FBAppCall *)presentShareDialogWithParams:(FBShareDialogParams *)params clientState:(NSDictionary *)clientState handler:(FBDialogAppCallCompletionHandler)handler;`

In the `FBShareDialogParams`, set the Array of Friends. 
works fine. But works only when the Facebook App is installed. Else doesnt work.

...

Can some please help me solve this problem:

1. Share on wall of multiple Friends.
2. Should work with or without the
   Facebook App being installed on phone.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must do something like:

```
FBShareDialogParams *p = [[FBShareDialogParams alloc] init];
p.friends = friendIdsArray;`
p.link = url;

//check if the FB app is installed and can use this method
if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:p]) {
    [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:p 
                                clientState:nil 
                                    handler:^(FBAppCall *call,
                                        NSDictionary *results,
                                               NSError *error) {
            //do some error checking
}
// fallback to what is essentially a webview
else {
    // string of comma separated Facebook Ids
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1234,5678", @"to", nil];
    NSString *message = @"I love Objective-C";
    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:[FBSession activeSession]
                                                  message:message 
                                                    title:nil 
                                               parameters:params
                                                  handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result,
                                                                    NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
              // do some error checking 
    }
```

This is what I use, the only problem I'm finding is that there appears to be some unknown limit to the number of Facebook Ids you can include when sending out a request.  It varies and depends on factors I can't find documented.  I think FB is trying to keep people from abusing/spamming people, for good reason....